# Java: command not found

Tags: java, bash, path

I have installed jdk on my mac, ran `/usr/libexec/java_home` and found the path to java to be this: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home`

I added this line to my `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I still get this error message:

> java: command not found

Can anyone help? I have been trying Stack Overflow solutions for hours now.

Thanks!

Comment: `java` is inside a `bin` folder in that location.

Answer (score 4):

While it is sufficient to add the "bin" folder to your PATH, doing so will leave you unable to run several desirable Java standard tools (like maven, ant, sbt, scala and groovy). Instead, first set a `JAVA_HOME` and then add that with "bin" to your PATH. Like,

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home"
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

Comment: @rsp Working on my mac; are you editing your ".bashrc"? If so, you need to re-source it before the changes take effect. `source .bashrc` - edit your question, and show us the result of `echo $PATH` if that doesn't resolve it.

Comment: @rsp You're welcome. Welcome to SO; please remember to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

You have set your `PATH` to the wrong variable. `Java` is inside a `bin` folder, which you have to append to your current path. The correct command would be:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
```

Comment: I found a bin folder in /Contents/Home and tried pointing to both that and java, but I still get an error msg

Comment: That's surprising, did you run the exact command in the answer?